# Can removing temporarily disconnecting filter damage car or not?

Tags: air-intake, air-filter, air

I bought a civic vti and when running the car the vtec didnt sound as loud as the test drive.

the seller told me that was because he removed the 'whales penis' modification which I had agreed to.  He then disconnected the pipe which goes to the air filter and said you can leave it like this it will sound louder.

I asked him wouldnt that cause damage since the filters not connected he replied 'not really'.

I'm not sure if the context of his answer was temporarily or long term.  In any case could leaving the car with the connecting pipe removed cause air damage in a temporary or long term scenario?

Thanks

Comment: To which side of the air filter was this tube connected? Engine side or not. Honda's tend to have long, convoluted tubes in front of the air filter. Removing a tube in this position would have less dire results than if you bypassed the air filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, yes! Removing the air filter can cause huge amounts of damage to the engine, as there's nothing to stop bits of debris getting into the cylinders - and if that happens, because most debris isn't very compressible, you get damage to the pistons, head, block, con-rods or some combination thereof...

You might be lucky and not get anything in there, but do you want to take the risk?

Comment: Just dusty air can cause accelerated wear rates...

Comment: All air is dusty just by different degrees and will cause damage. Especially if accelerated to a high speed- think  sandblasting